# Django. Mostrar edad en template a partir fecha nacimiento

Tags: django

Soy novato. Estoy intentando mostrar en una tabla la edad en función de la fecha de nacimiento.
En views:

```
def pacientes(request):
todosPacientes = Pacientes.objects.all()
fechaActual = date.today()
            
return render(request, 'crud/pacientes.html', {'todosPacientes': todosPacientes, 'fechaActual' : fechaActual})
```

En plantilla

```
<td>{{ pac.fecha_nac - fechaActual }}</td>
```

Me da error Could not parse the remainder: ' - fechaActual' from 'pac.fecha_nac - fechaActual'
He probado muchas opciones pero no hay manera

Answer (score 0):

Podrías implementar un método en tu modelo Pacientes para que calcule la edad en función a su fecha de nacimiento, iría algo así:

```
from datetime import date
class Pacientes(models.Model):
    ### Aqui van tus campos

    @property
    def edad_actual(self):
        """
        Calcular edad actual basado en fecha de nacimiento
        :return: int edad
        """
        if self.fecha_nac:
            # Obtener fecha de hoy
            today = date.today()
            # Calcular Edad
            age = today.year - self.fecha_nac.year - (
                    (today.month, today.day) < (self.fecha_nac.month, self.fecha_nac.day))
            return age

        # Si no tiene fecha su edad es 0
        return 0
```

Y en tu template ya solo colocarías:

```
<td>{{ pac.edad_actual }}</td>
```

Comment: Genial!!! Había estado cerca pero no lo había podido hacer. Funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como aceptada para futuras referencias para personas con la misma duda.